# What does the start_ar_lags attribute do in an ARMA model?

Tags: time-series, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

I am using the ARMA model from the statsmodel library.

It have seen this parameter start_ar_lags set when the error:

```
ValueError: The computed initial AR coefficients are not stationary
You should induce stationarity, choose a different model order, or you can
pass your own start_params.
```

One example had non-stationary data and after getting this error they added start_ar_lags parameter.

```
model_ar_6_ma_6 = ARMA(df.market_value, order=(6,6))
results_ar_6_ma_6 = model_ar_6_ma_6.fit(start_ar_lags = 11)
```

This worked, but what does start_ar_lags do. Does the ARMA model still use 6 and 6 lags for the AR and MA respectively.

The documentation says:

```
 If start_ar_lags is not None, fits an AR process with a lag length equal to start_ar_lags.
```

Does it actually change the number of lags in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start_ar_lags` is an argument of `_fit_start_params_hr` method which is used to get starting parameters for fit. This method first fits an AR process of order that is selected via best BIC if `start_ar_lags` is `None`. If `start_ar_lags` is not `None`, it fits an AR process of order `start_ar_lags`. Then, using residuals of this AR fit, it fits an ARMA process of order `(p, q)` that you specified in the `ARMA()` constructor, and that is used as a first guess at the starting parameters, and the overall model fit continues from here.

So no, it does not affect your model order.

Comment: Thanks. So the ARMA need a AR process to be ran before?

Comment: In this particular implementation - yes.